# Can't find top defects table from report

Tags: allure, test-reporting

Recently trying the new version of Allure, Allure2, I can't find the top defects table from the report. Categories currently don't group Errors together :

In Allure version 1:

[image: Top Defects in Allure]

In Allure version 2:
[image: Categories Defect in Allure2]

I should have the 3 errors (org.Apache.commons.codec.EncoderException) grouped together since they are the same Exception.

Is there any way to get the Top Defects table in the Allure2 report ?

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: @Rob: The errors code are not important for that topic. There is no reason to have them written by text. I can change them, throw what ever exception I want. What is important is that the errors are not grouped together. Even more, peoples who find this topic by searching the errors display on the image will feel my question not relevant to their search.